# Updating chart.js with a dataset of different size not working

Tags: chart.js

I have a bar chart that I am setting up like this:

```
const BarChart = {
    chart: null,
    init(data, labels) {
        const canvas = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        const options =  {...defaultOptions};
        options.data.labels = labels;
        options.data.datasets[0].data = data;
        this.chart = new Chart(canvas, options);
    }
};

const defaultOptions = {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
        datasets: [
            {
                backgroundColor: "#006BE8",
                borderColor: "rgba(151,187,205,1)",
                barPercentage: 0.9,
                categoryPercentage: 0.9,
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        legend: {
            display: false
        },
        scales: {
            yAxes: [
                {
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: '#736B8A',
                        beginAtZero: true,
                        stepSize: 100
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }
            ],
            xAxes: [
                {
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: '#736B8A'
                    },
                    gridLines: {
                        display: false
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

I am initiating the bar chart like this:

```
BarChart.init(getData(selectedRegionID), getLabels());
```

The initial data is 40 elements long integer array.
And that works fine, but when I try to update the chart like this:

```
BarChart.chart.data.labels = monthsShortString;
BarChart.chart.data.datasets[0].data = OvernightsByMonth;
BarChart.chart.update();
```

Where `monthsShortString` is an array:

```
['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
```

And `OvernightsByMonth` is an array of integers:

```
[552246, 608557, 1010465, 2929136, 4733930, 12609027, 25256705, 27455440, 10560193, 3215752, 939206, 826070]
```

I get then:

```
main.da4909e4.js:2238 Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at computeLabelSizes (main.da4909e4.js:25313)
    at ChartElement._getLabelSizes (main.da4909e4.js:25982)
    at ChartElement.fit (main.da4909e4.js:25827)
    at ChartElement.update (main.da4909e4.js:25622)
    at fitBoxes (main.da4909e4.js:21198)
    at Object.update (main.da4909e4.js:21409)
    at Chart.updateLayout (main.da4909e4.js:23751)
    at Chart.update (main.da4909e4.js:23704)
    at tourismBarChart (main.da4909e4.js:30529)
    at renderBarChart (main.da4909e4.js:30508)
```

I can see that the values for labels and dataset are updated, but I still get that error.

I have even tried with using the destroy method on a chart object and creating a new chart object after that:

```
BarChart.chart.destroy();
BarChart.init(OvernightsByMonth, monthsShortString);
```

But, then I get:

Uncaught (in promise) RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded

```
at computeLabelSizes (main.da4909e4.js:25363)
at ChartElement._getLabelSizes (main.da4909e4.js:26032)
at ChartElement.fit (main.da4909e4.js:25877)
at ChartElement.update (main.da4909e4.js:25672)
at fitBoxes (main.da4909e4.js:21248)
at Object.update (main.da4909e4.js:21459)
at Chart.updateLayout (main.da4909e4.js:23801)
at Chart.update (main.da4909e4.js:23754)
at Chart.construct (main.da4909e4.js:23478)
at new Chart (main.da4909e4.js:23415)
```

I have even tried with removing canvas:

```
BarChart.chart.destroy();
document.getElementById('canvas').remove(); 
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas'); 
canvas.setAttribute('id','canvas'); 
document.querySelector('.chart-legend').insertAdjacentElement('afterend', canvas);
BarChart.init(OvernightsByMonth, monthsShortString);
```

But, if I am updating chart with the same type of dataset, just different values, but same length of data, then it works fine.

```
BarChart.chart.data.labels = getLabels();
BarChart.chart.data.datasets[0].data = getData(selectedRegionID);
BarChart.chart.update();
```

What am I doing wrong here, how should I update bar chart with new data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that the values in the new dataset where of much bigger magnitude, so the chart wasn't able to calculate the size with current `stepSize`. When I changed that, then it worked fine:

```
BarChart.chart.options.scales.yAxes[0].ticks.stepSize = 500000;
```